# Django: Change HTML template's font in the middle of a text string that is generated by a {{variable}}

Tags: python, html, django

I have a character string generated in views.py like this:

```
context_dict['advice'] = "Please consider selecting " + var1 + 
                         " as your next choice."
```

This is displayed in a page whose template has invoked it like this:

```
{% if advice %}
My advice:
<p style="font-size:20px; color:blue">
<b>{{advice}}</b>
</p>
```

Thus, the entire sentence comes out with the same font: 20px, blue, and bold. However, I would like the word contained in `var1` to be green instead of blue (with the rest of the sentence still blue), so that it stands out.

I don't see a way to do this. I considered moving more of the static text to the template, so that I could just make `var1` the variable and apply a different font to it. This kind of approach won't work for now though, because the text that appears static in this example could actually change to 100+ different things depending on what happens in the control flow logic of `views.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try like this:

```
context_dict['advice'] = "Please consider selecting <span style='{0}'>{1}</span> as your next choice.".format('color:green;', var1)
```

This requires you to change the variable in the HTML template to:

```
{{advice | safe}}
```

Comment: This would not parse the html inside of the string

Comment: Oh, didn't know that! I retract my statement :P I would include that in your answer just to be comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by separating the strings into three variables. The beginning string, the variable, and the end of the string. This will still allow all three to change with the flow of the program.

## views

```
context['str1'] = 'Please consider selecting '
context['var1'] = var1
context['str2'] = ' as your next choice.'
```

## template

```
<div class="class1">{{ str1 }}</div>
<div class="class2">{{ var1 }}</div>
<div class="class1">{{ str2 }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you possibly set the `dict` key to a `list`? If so, try:

```
context_dict['advice'] = ["Please consider selecting ", var1, " as your next choice."]
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<b>{{advice[0]}}</b><span style="color: green;">{{advice[1]}}</span><b>{{advice[2]}}</b>
```